# How to find a graph's equation from its points

Tags: interpolation, data-analysis

I have a set of data that constitutes the graph on the picture.  What I want to know is how would I find the equation equivalent to that kind of graph? The X are on the interval $[1,10]$.[image: Graph]

Comment: There are infinitely many!

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Comment: (@kjetil: Sorry to be the spelling police, but you mean "Welcome".)

Comment: Without any other information, I would suggest a straight line obtained by least-square fit.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i have the (x,y) of the points 1 to 10

Comment: As said, you cannot do much without any idea about the model. Did you try a linear regression ? If you post the points, I would do it. Cheers :-)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). There are many solutions to it, but basically in the case of your sample, you could try a [polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Polynomial_interpolation) or splines.

The more points you add to the calculation of the polynomial, the more specific and closer to the graph it will get, but at the same time the function will get more complex.

For instance, there is a nice online [interpolation calculator here](http://www.solvemymath.com/online_math_calculator/interpolation.php) that makes linear, cubic spline and Lagrange interpolation, so you can choose the function that is closer to your original set of data.